# Decrease execution time for a given database-handling Python 2.7 program.

Tags: mysql, performance, python-2.7

The following function fetches data from a database:

```
def findid(name,parent):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                       user = "arunkamaly",
                        passwd = "code",
                       db = "se")
    cursor=conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(" select xbrl_id from se_xbrl_concepts where xbrl_name=%s;",name)
    name=cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.execute(" select xbrl_id from se_xbrl_concepts where xbrl_name=%s;",parent)
    pname=cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    if pname==None:
            return name[0],0
    return name[0],pname[0]
```

And here the function above is used, but also the insert method introduced:

```
def prsentparse():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",\
                       user = "arunkamaly",\
                        passwd = "code",\
                       db = "se")
    cursor=conn.cursor()

    f = open(csvfile, 'rb')
    spamReader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for clist in spamReader:
            if clist[0]=='LinkRole' or clist[0] =='' or clist[0]=='prefix':
                    continue
            name=clist[0]+':'+clist[1]

            parent=clist[6].strip()
            xid,pid=findid(name,parent)
            prio=0 if clist[5].strip()=='' else clist[5]
            order=0 if clist[4].strip()=='' else clist[4]
            depth=0 if clist[3].strip()=='' else clist[3]
    #print clist
            #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO se_xbrl_presentation (xbrl_id,xbrl_parent_id,priority,order,depth) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(xid,pid,prio,order,depth) )
    #sql = "insert into se_xbrl_presentation (xbrl_id, xbrl_parent_id, priority, order, depth) values (" + xid + ", " + pid + ", " + prio + ", " + order + ", " + depth + ");"
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `se_xbrl_presentation`(`xbrl_id`, `xbrl_parent_id`, `priority`, `order`, `depth`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(xid,pid,prio,order,depth) )
    except MySQLdb.Error,e:
        print "mysql Error %d:%s"%(e.args[0],e.args[1])
conn.commit
cursor.close()
```

This approach appears to be too slow. Could you please advise any performance-increasing improvements?

Comment: Numbers numbers numbers please. Define slow. What parts of the code are slow? How did you measure it? When you know what needs optimisation then I'm sure people will be able to help. But from a cursory glance you're using cursors to interact with a relational db. You might want to read up a Sets vs Cursors as a startgin point.

Comment: For execute the program need hours

Comment: @user14.... I understand that. But you need to investgate further to see what bit of the code is slow.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a connection inside the findid function. That means that you are opening a connection in every iteration of the for loop. Instead, pass the connection that you already have to the findid function and you won't have to open one every time.

Another thing that could be important: do you have an index in the xbrl_name field of the se_xbrl_concepts table? You are doing two selects in each iteration of the for loop.